# Can 'I believe' and 'I think' have different connotations?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, connotation

Can '*believe*' have a different meaning/connotation than '*think*'?

I think you would use 'believe' if you want to stress that the thing that you **believe** will happen means very much to you and you are convinced it will definitely happen. **Think**, however, is less emotional and you don't stress whether you are convinced or not sure if something will happen - it is neutral.

For example:

> I **think** he will win.

-> neutral position, based on what someone sees

> I **believe** he will win.

-> Convinced he will win, emotional

Would you say that is the case?

Comment: There is some logic for your interpretation, but I suspect actual usage and preferences would be closer to random.

Comment: I believe i think i have the answer but i am unsure as to its validity. A belief is matter of faith not  supported by facts.  A thought may or may not be the result of research and study leading to a conclusion. There are those who would say " i believe therefore i think "   they are mistaken.  Do not believe everything you think.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Comment: According to what I read, believe implies that you simply suppose something. Think, I thought, is clear. Just was not sure about believe and whether the emotional connotation is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the connotations, just as the actual meanings, of "I believe" and "I think" are different. They are close in meaning, but "I beieve" tends to express it more strongly. In belief, you not only think it, but typically are committed to that thought. They can be used interchangeably, though.

1. I think the square root of 170 is about 13.

Neutral.  It is a thought you have.

2. I believe the square root of 170 is about 13.

You've thought about your thought, and agree with it.

3. I know the square root of 170 is 13.038 etc.

You've calculated it yourself (or used a calculator).